# Sum of two sets and their multiplication

Tags: number-theory

I have two sets of numbers that fulfill:

1. $s_1+s_2+\dots+s_n=q_1+q_2+\dots+q_n$
2. $s_1^2+s_2^2+\dots+s_n^2<q_1^2+q_2^2+\dots+q_n^2$

I need to show that:
$$
(1+s_1)(1+s_2)\dotsm(1+s_n)>(1+q_1)(1+q_2)\dotsm(1+q_n)
$$

This is not the start point of the question, it is just as far as I got.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If $|s_i|\ll1$ and $|q_i|\ll1$ for all $i$ then your inequality is true.

From $\bigl(\sum_i s_i\bigr)^2=\bigl(\sum_i q_i\bigr)^2$ and $\sum_i s_i^2<\sum_i q_i^2$ we conclude that $$\sum_{i<j} s_is_j>\sum_{i<j} q_iq_j\ .\tag{1}$$

Write $\epsilon s_i$ instead of $s_i$ and $\epsilon q_i$ instead of $q_i$ with$|\epsilon|\ll1$. Then
$$\prod_i\bigl(1+\epsilon s_i\bigr)= 1+\epsilon\sum_i s_i+\epsilon^2\sum_{i<j} s_is_j+o(\epsilon^2)\qquad(\epsilon\to0)\ ,$$
and similarly for the $q_i$. From $(1)$ we then can infer that in fact
$$\prod_i\bigl(1+\epsilon s_i\bigr)>\prod_i\bigl(1+\epsilon q_i\bigr)$$
when $|\epsilon|$ is small.